# Delete the temp file using c# not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am trying to save the excel file in temp, send the email, and then delete the excel file. 
So I make a foreach loop to delete the file.
But my code don't delete the file after sending the email.

I have the error message:

> System.IO.IOException:The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\huh\AppData\Local\Temp\employee.xls'  because it is being used by another process.

I am using Quartz in ASP.Net to send email periodically.

```
    private void SendEmail()
    {
        DataTable data = GetData();
        Excel.ApplicationClass excel = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true); // true for object template???

          ....
        string path = @Path.GetTempPath() + "employee.xls";

        workbook.SaveAs(path,
        Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, missing, missing,
        false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
        missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);

        workbook.Close();
         ...........

        using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(from, to))
        {
           SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            mm.Subject = "List";
            mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(path));
            .....
            smtp.Send(mm);

            try
            {
                 File.Delete(path);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 this.WriteToFile(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't have an empty catch. If you either a) didn't wrap the delete operation in a try/catch, or b) did something in the catch to handle/report the exception, then you'd have a good start on an idea of why the deletion is failing.

Comment: Also, Excel has probably still got the file open, so if you examined the Exception ex, you will see that it is "Access is denied". You will need to tell Excel to release the file.

Comment: The file is likely locked by the `Excel` save method. What is the exception?

Comment: Did you close the Excel file before trying to delete it? I dont see anything in your code that does that, and it is required if you want to delete it.

Comment: @braX oh Yeah I did it ! I edit my code

Comment: @FusRoDah System.IO.IOException: 'C:\Users\huh\AppData\Local\Temp\employee.xls' The process cannot access the file '{0}' because it is being used by another process. This is the error message.

Comment: This is why you're [not supposed to use the Interop libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) within ASP.NET. Use a library capable of working directly with the files from .NET code, such as EPPlus, NPOI, Closed XML, Office XML SDK, Aspose etc.

Comment: I tried to look EPPlus, and Close XML but they can't make a xls file so that I use Interop. Is there any option I can make a xls file? Because I search it and the only option I could make it was Interop. @mason

Comment: Did you look at *all* the options I presented you with? I don't think you did. And anyways, why do you think you must generate XLS? Why can't you use XLSX?

Comment: @mason because iphone can't open the XLSX file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461068/iphone-unable-to-open-closedxml-from-gmail-com That was my problem.

Comment: You didn't look at all the libraries I presented you with. And your other question doesn't say what app you're trying to open it with and doesn't provide an MCVE.

Comment: @mason Thanks! I solve every problems using NPOI.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to quit the `excel` application before deleting the file. Try something like this:

```
workbook.Close(true);
excel.Quit();
```